# Ffmpeg Gaussian Filter (gblur) kernel size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am applying a Gaussian filter to a video using [ffmpeg's gblur-filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#gblur). The filter accepts the sigma option, but does not allow to choose the kernel size. To correctly report on my Gaussian blur usage, I would like to know which kernel sized is used in ffmpeg. (FYI, I used sigma = 0.5 and sigma = 0.8.)

Now, [this StackExchange question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10057/gaussian-blur-standard-deviation-radius-and-kernel-size) theoretically discusses the relationship between sigma, radius and kernel size. If I interpret the answers correctly, then radius = 2 * sigma. And the radius is the amount of pixels in each direction that the Gaussian filter uses. Thus, kernel_size = ceil(radius*2 + 1). For example, if sigma = 0.5, then it's a 3x3 kernel, while if sigma = 0.8, then it's a 5x5 kernel.

On the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur#Mathematics) says: "Typically, an image processing program need only calculate a matrix with dimensions ceil(6*sigma) x ceil(6*sigma) to ensure a result sufficiently close to that obtained by the entire Gaussian distribution." Thus, again, if sigma = 0.5, then it's a 3x3 kernel, while if sigma = 0.8, then it's a 5x5 kernel.

However, I found a scientific paper titled "[A Low Complexity Video Watermarking in H.264 Compressed Domain](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5582233/)" that contradicts the previous statements.
The authors claim to have used a Gaussian Filter 5x5 with sigma = 0.3 and sigma = 0.4 (in Table III and Table IV). But for those sigma's, I would expect a kernel size of 3x3?

In short, I am confused on how to deduct the kernel size used in ffmpeg, while I can only change sigma. I also do not get any wiser by reading the [ffmpeg gblur source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_gblur.c). Is there someone who can give me clarity around this subject? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this topic here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the kernel size is a discrete kernel truncated from the continuous Normal Distribution, which is for satisfying the requirements of using convolution.

It's correct that only the sigma is requested to input. I supposed you want to know this one: About 68% of values drawn from a normal distribution are within one standard deviation σ away from the mean; about 95% of the values lie within two standard deviations, and about 99.7% are within three standard deviations. This fact is known as the [68-95-99.7 (empirical) rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) or the 3-sigma rule.

So that's why the kernel size is 3x3 when sigma is 0.5. It's simply 0.5 * 3 = 1.5, and for its symmetry, the final kernel size is 3 in the case of 1D Normal Distribution. For the 2D case, it's 3x3.